# Groovy - How to check if a json key exists

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I'm creating a REST Mock that will receive as input a JSON request:

```
{  
     "infoSimIn":{
        "idenficationSim":[ 
            { 
                "imsi":123456789012345
            }
          ]
       } 
}
```

How can i check if my JSON contains  `imsi` Key, before returning the appropriate response ?

Thanks u..

Comment: `request.infoSimIn.idenficationSim.first().imsi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the script that shows you if `imsi` is present in the json

```
def str = """
{  "infoSimIn":{
        "idenficationSim":[ 
            { 
                "imsi":123456789012345
            }
          ]
       } 
}"""
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(str)
def result = json.infoSimIn.idenficationSim.collect { it.keySet().contains('imsi')}[0]
assert result == true, 'json does not have imsi'
```

You can quickly check online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5121418928848896)</kbd>

**EDIT: based on OP comment**
Change from:

```
def str = ...
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(str)
```

To

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent)
```

EDIT : based on OP's comment and it works successfully unlike op complains null

[image]

And in the Mock service:

[image]

Comment: thanks you for ur answer, but if i want to retrieve it from request , how can i do it ? whitout using `def str`

Comment: @FuSsA, did you try the answer? Hope it is helpful and resolves the issue.

Comment: @FuSsA, it is surprising which worked yesterday and null now. what has changed drastically?

Comment: @FuSsA, not sure, there was a typo in `assert` line which I updated now.

Comment: Yesterday i have tested using ur first code on Groovy web console.. but now when i have tried to use it SoapUI  `log.info(result)` return `null`..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142640/discussion-between-rao-and-fussa).